# Reanimar un botón según lo necesite

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo una consulta:

Estoy haciendo un sistema de login dinámico con `Ajax`, `jQuery` y `php`. Actualmente todo funciona como quiero, el único detalle es que si los datos coinciden con lo que el usuario coloca en el login, lo redireccione a otra página (como las típicas paginas de login). El problema es que no logro hacer que la página redireccione si la consulta fue válida, que es lo que espero.

[image: Esta es la que se encarga de enviar la petición a la base de datos]

y este sería mi `Ajax` que procesa la información que recibe:

[image: T]

Todo funciona como quiero, lo único es que no consigo la forma de que redireccione a otra página cuando los datos son correctos.

Comment: Ya probaste con `top.location.href="login.htm";`

Comment: Si pegas el código (escrito) en vez de imágenes, seguro que la comunidad podría ayudarte mucho mejor

Comment: Pienso lo mismo, seria muchisimo mas facil para leer y hasta para copiar y testear algo

Answer (score 0):

si ya intentaste con el header de php para redireccionar y no te funcionó puedes intentarlo desde jquery, en lugar del alert('done'), intenta con

```
window.location.href = "larutaadireccionar/algo";
```

Comment: Si, ya lo intente, inclusive con setTimeout(URL, time); y nada. no me redirecciona

Answer (score 0):

La forma que logre hacerlo funcionar, fue agregando este fragmento de código:

```
setTimeout(' window.location.href = "index.php"; ',4000);
```